# Why do we need another schema for schema stitching?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm reading a [blog](https://www.robinwieruch.de/graphql-apollo-server-tutorial) to separate graphql schemas and resolvers by domain.

To merge the resolvers, it makes sense.

```
import userResolver from "./User";
import messageResolver from "./Message";

export default [userResolver, messageResolver];
```

But for the schema, why do we need another schema(linkSchema)?

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";
import userSchema from "./User";
import messageSchema from "./Message";

const linkSchema = gql`
  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }

  type Mutation {
    _: Boolean
  }

  type Subscription {
    _: Boolean
  }
`;

export default [linkSchema, userSchema, messageSchema];
```

> In this file, both schemas are merged with the help of a utility
>   called linkSchema. The linkSchema defines all types shared within the
>   schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the blog describes is combining type definitions like this:

```
const typeDefsA = `
  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }
`

const typeDefsB = `
  extend type Query {
    someField: String
  }
`
```

To call this **schema stitching** is a *misnomer*. [Schema stitching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/schema-stitching) involves combining multiple, separate GraphQL services into a single schema. The article you linked only describes structuring your project so that the *type definitions for your single schema are located across multiple files*.

That aside, all we're doing is what would be otherwise a single string representing our schema and splitting it into multiple strings that we then combine. We want to be able to define fields for our `Query` and `Mutation` types across these type definitions as well. However, we can't just do this:

```
type Query {
  someField: Boolean
}

type Query {
  someOtherField: String
}
```

Doing so will result in an error because we've defined two types with the same name. Instead, we have to use the `extend` keyword to `extend` an existing type:

```
type Query {
  someField: Boolean
}

# this says "add these fields to our existing type"
extend type Query {
  someOtherField: String
}

# so does this
extend type Query {
  yetAnotherField: String
}
```

However, in order to use the `extend` keyword, we must have at least one type to actually extend. Doing this will also throw an error:

```
extend type Query {
  someField: Boolean
}

extend type Query {
  someOtherField: String
}
```

Given that, when splitting up your type definitions, it's common to have a base type definitions string that provides the base types for the three operations (Query, Mutation and Subscription). Then all your other type definitions can safely extend these types without worry. These "base" type definitions are also a good location for types that are shared across different files.

Lastly, note that it's also not necessary to provide any fields for the base operation types when doing this. Provided that you do extend the base operation types elsewhere in your schema, you can just do:

```
type Query

extend type Query {
  someField: String
}
```